# Why does within set column to NA instead of 0

Tags: r

Taking the dataset from here:
[how to insert a new column in a dataset with values if it satisfies a statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674930/how-to-insert-a-new-column-in-a-dataset-with-values-if-it-satisfies-a-statement/)

```
df1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text = "
    Chr start       end     num.mark    seg.mean    id
    1   68580000    68640000    8430    0.7       gain
    1   115900000   116260000   8430    0.0039    loss
    1   173500000   173680000   5      -1.7738    loss
    1   173500000   173680000   12       0.011    loss
    1   173840000   174010000   6      -1.6121    loss")
```

Why does the following `within` statement result in `NA`'s in the Occurance column?

```
within(df1, {Occurance <- 0 
             Occurance[seg.mean >= 0.5 & id == "gain"] <- 1
             Occurance[seg.mean <= -0.5 & id == "loss"] <- -1})
```

Result:

```
  Chr     start       end num.mark seg.mean   id Occurance
1   1  68580000  68640000     8430   0.7000 gain         1
2   1 115900000 116260000     8430   0.0039 loss        NA
3   1 173500000 173680000        5  -1.7738 loss        -1
4   1 173500000 173680000       12   0.0110 loss        NA
5   1 173840000 174010000        6  -1.6121 loss        -1
```

If i do it in two steps:

```
df2 <- within(df1, Occurance <- 0)
within(df2, {Occurance[seg.mean >= 0.5 & id == "gain"] <- 1;
             Occurance[seg.mean <= -0.5 & id == "loss"] <- -1})
```

I do get the hoped-for result

```
  Chr     start       end num.mark seg.mean   id Occurance
1   1  68580000  68640000     8430   0.7000 gain         1
2   1 115900000 116260000     8430   0.0039 loss         0
3   1 173500000 173680000        5  -1.7738 loss        -1
4   1 173500000 173680000       12   0.0110 loss         0
5   1 173840000 174010000        6  -1.6121 loss        -1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has to do with how vectors are initialized and extended in R. For example

```
a <- 0
a[1:10>5] <- 2
# [1]  0 NA NA NA NA  2  2  2  2  2
```

When you first create `a`, it has length 1. When you assign to indexes that don't exist, R created those indexes and fills in missing values with NA values. That's basically what's happening in your example. R doesn't merge that your new columns to the data.frame till your code block is complete.

Your step-method works because the single element vector of 0 is recycled to the full length of the data.frame after the first `within()` ends.

Why not use a more vectorized approach.

```
within(df1, {Occurance <- 
     ifelse(seg.mean >= 0.5 & id == "gain", 1, 
     ifelse(seg.mean <= -0.5 & id == "loss", -1, 0))
})
```

or you can just initialize Occurance to the correct length

```
within(df1, {Occurance <- rep(0, length( seg.mean))
    Occurance[seg.mean >= 0.5 & id == "gain"] <- 1
    Occurance[seg.mean <= -0.5 & id == "loss"] <- -1
})
```